# Share file between 2 repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge, git-subtree

Given the 2 following repositories:

```
webapp-repoA/
    src/
        main/
            java/
            resources/
                toshare/theFile.txt
            webapp/
        test/
    .gitignore

dbRefact-repoB/
    src/
        main/
            java/
            resources/
        test/
    .gitignore
```

What is the sequence of 'subtree' commands to get the file "**toshare/theFile.txt**" located in the "**webapp-RepoA**" repository to be copied to the "resources" folder of the  "**dbRefact-repoB**" repository?

I do not want to create a third repository. Changes to "**theFile.txt**" will be from the repository **"webapp-RepoA**".  I do not want all the contents of the "**webapp-RepoA**" repository in the "**dbRefact-repoB**", only the  "**toshare/theFile.txt**" file.

Comment: Thank you Antarr thank you. However, this is not a duplicate since unfortunately the link you mention only deals with 'git submodule' and not with 'git subtree'.